# Use pandas to select the lagged row along with current row based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, shift

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
person_id  source_system   r_diff
  1              A          NULL
  1              B           0
  1              B           9
  1              A           15
  1              A           574
  1              B           0
  1              A           63
  1              A           136
  1              B           0
```

I would like to select data based on Or operation of 2 rules

a) Select all records where source_system = B

b) Select n and n-1 rows where r_diff = 0.

For example, in the above data, you can find r_diff = 0 for row numbers 2,6,9. So, I would like to select rows 1,2 and 5,6 and 8,9. You can see how I have chosen n and n-1 rows

I tried the below

```
df['flag_1'] = np.where((df['source_system'] == 'B'), '1','0')
df['flag_2'] = np.where((df['r_diff'] == 0), '1','0')
df['flag_3'] = np.where((df['r_diff'].shift(-1) == 0, '1','0')
df = df[((df['flag_1'] == '1') or (df['flag_2'] == '1') or (df['flag_3'] == '1'))]
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
person_id  source_system   r_diff
  1              A          NULL
  1              B           0
  1              B           9
  1              A           574
  1              B           0
  1              A           136
  1              B           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close, you can set mask to variables and chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` like:

```
m1 = df['source_system'] == 'B'
m2 = df['r_diff'] == 0
m3 = df.groupby('person_id')['r_diff'].shift(-1) == 0

df = df[m1 | m2 | m3]
print (df)
   person_id source_system  r_diff
0          1             A     NaN
1          1             B     0.0
2          1             B     9.0
4          1             A   574.0
5          1             B     0.0
7          1             A   136.0
8          1             B     0.0
```

Comment: I know the output is correct but is there anyway to group by `person_id` and get the same output?

Comment: @TheGreat - Editde answer.